# why my listview can be scroll with few items in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am working with an app which scan all  Wifi Aps around. The main problem is that i can scroll the screen with no items. this behavior happens when i refresh too many times then  i have less widgets than before

[image: Behavior in GIF]

**this is how i refresh my listview**

```
 RefreshIndicator(
  key: refreshKey,
  onRefresh: () async {
    setState(() {
      _wifiNetworkList.removeRange(0, _wifiNetworkList.length);
    });
    await _refreshList();
  },
    


  Future<Null> _refreshList() async {
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
_getWifiList();
return null;
}

 Future<void> _getWifiList() async {
WifiConnectionObject wifiConnectionObject =
await wifiConfiguration.connectedToWifi();

if (wifiConnectionObject != null) {

  var _wifiNetworkListLocal;
  _wifiNetworkListLocal = await wifiConfiguration.getWifiList();
  setState(() {
    _wifiNetworkList = _wifiNetworkListLocal;
  }
  );
 }
```

My listviewBuilder

```
ListView.builder(

      itemCount: _wifiNetworkList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        WifiNetwork wifiNetwork = _wifiNetworkList[index];
        _checkStateColor(wifiNetwork.ssid.substring(0, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `shrinkWrap` property of the ListView.builder to `true`:

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  ...
```